# how can do signup form include fname last name etc on firebase using android studio

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

this code for signup form on firebase using an android studio and it's working fine but I need to add first name, last name, gender with the signup form, and record to a firebase user group and direct go to a specific group

This picture shows what I want and I do it manually.

[image]

```
package com.example.showapps;

    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.util.Patterns;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ProgressBar;
    import android.widget.TextView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class signupActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

EditText s_email, s_password, s_cpasserd , fname,lname,phone;
ProgressBar progressBar;
FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_signup);

    s_email = findViewById(R.id.s_email);
    s_password = findViewById(R.id.s_password);
    s_cpasserd = findViewById(R.id.s_cpassword);
    lname= findViewById(R.id.s_lname);
    fname = findViewById(R.id.s_fname);
    phone= findViewById(R.id.s_phone);

    firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
    progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBar2);
    findViewById(R.id.btn_signup).setOnClickListener(this);
    findViewById(R.id.mTologin).setOnClickListener(this);

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.btn_signup:
            signup();
            break;
        case R.id.mTologin:
            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), login_Activity.class));
            break;
    }
}

private void signup() {
    String email = s_email.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = s_password.getText().toString().trim();
    String cpassword = s_cpasserd.getText().toString().trim();
    String fname= s_fname.getText().toString().trim();
    String lname = s_lname.getText().toString().trim();
    String phone = s_phone.getText().toString().trim();

    if (email.isEmpty()) {
        s_email.setError("The Email is required");
        s_email.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(email).matches()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The Email is regietered", 
    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
    if (password.length() < 6) {
        s_password.setError("The password is less than 6 characters");
        s_password.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (password.isEmpty()) {
        s_password.setError("The password is required");
        s_password.requestFocus();
        return;
    }
    if (cpassword.isEmpty()) {
        s_password.setError("The comfirm password is required");
        s_password.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    if(!cpassword.equals(password)){
        s_cpasserd.setError("The password is not much! ");
        s_cpasserd.requestFocus();
        return;
    }

    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new 
    OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error ! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The user has been registered ", 
   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), login_Activity.class));


            }
        }
    });
   }
  }
```

here what i need to add for this code to complete my task ?

```
firebaseAuth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).addOnCompleteListener(new 
OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
@Override
public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

   progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
      if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Error ! ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            } else {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The user has been registered ", 
Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), login_Activity.class));


            }
        }
    });
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the `else` statement, you need to send the data to firestore:

```
 } else {

     Map<String, Object> userInfo = new HashMap<>();
       city.put("name", "name_here");
       city.put("gender", "gender_here");
       city.put("email", email);
     FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
     db.collection("customer _user").document("1")
        .set(userInfo)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
             Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot successfully written!");
             Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The user has been registered ", 
             Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
             startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), login_Activity.class));
            }
        })
        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                Log.w(TAG, "Error writing document", e);
            }
        });
}
```

Create a `hashmap` then using `set` you can add the data to the document and navigate to the other activity in case it was successful.